# Problem with defining Solr_home

Tags: search, solr, configure, lucene

Hallo,

I am configuring Solr. Everything ist working fine but one thing appears to be weird to me. 
I have Solr running on Tomcat. My Solr_home ist defined somewhere on my hard drive through JNDI. For some reason Solr creates on startup a new folder of solr inside of Tomcat's Webapps folder with the lib files and the index. That alone would make me think that I somehow defined Solr_home wrong but Solr is using the schema and config out of the real Solr_home. I just can't get any sense into that. Is that how Solr works or can anyone give me a hint on how I can force Solr to saving the index into my defined Solr_home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at setting the `solr.data.dir`. See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml). The default is `./solr/data` which I suppose is relative to the webapps path.